# Upload profile picture or image of user in Spring Boot, JavaScript and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I have online shopping project in Spring Boot. There is a user profile page in which user is able to update his/her profile picture. As for now, profile pic is uploaded successfully but when I refresh or reload the page, new uploaded image is not showing. Each time I need to logout and re-login then I am able to see my updated image.

Below is the script to upload image to server. Here I have created REST API to convert file into URL and then saving that URL into my database.

```
  $("#file").change(function(){
        var formData = new FormData();
          var fileSelect = document.getElementById("file");
          if(fileSelect.files && fileSelect.files.length == 1) {
              var file = fileSelect.files[0];
              formData.set("file",file,file.name);
              }else{
                  $("#file").focus();
                  return false;
              }
          var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          try {
                request.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if(request.readyState==4) {
                        var v = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                        if(v.status==="OK") {
                            document.getElementById('imagepath').value = v.response; // Fetched image url from DB and set into a hidden input field.
                            userprofilepic();
                        }
                    }
                }
                request.open('POST',"<%=AkApiUrl.uploadfile%>");
                request.send(formData);
              } catch(e) {
                  swal("Unable to connect to server","","error");
              }
    })
```

This is the function where user profile pic is uploaded and can be seen.

```
    function userprofilepic(){
        var img = document.getElementById('imagepath').value;
        var url = "api/updateprofilepic";
        $.post(url, {
            userid : '<%=loginuserid%>',
            img : img,
        }, function(data, status) {
            if (data.status == "OK") {
                if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                    swal({title: "Yippee! Image Uploaded!", text: "User Image Uploaded Successfully", type: "success"},
                        function(){
                            location.reload();
                    })
                } else {
                    var error = data.responseMessage;
                    swal(error, "", "error");
                }
            } else {
                var error = data.responseMessage;
                swal(error, "", "error");
            }
        });
    }
```

**Please help me by suggesting possible solution to upload profile image and it should be visible when user reload the page or when uploaded.**

[Screenshot to display user profile image field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSqRs.png)